# Pointer to array of pointers results in seg fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I'm working on a project for school, and faced this elementary problem (it's not part of the assignment, merely a set-back in the initial stage of the problem).

I am trying to create a pointer that points to an array. The array contains pointers, each of which points to a class object "Customer".

Here is [customer.h](http://pastebin.com/CgbZBy8G).
Here is [customer.cpp](http://pastebin.com/EMdt5ZqP).

Finally, here is my main, which is causing problems:

```
#include "customer.h"

int main () {
    Customer** c_array;
    c_array = new Customer*[10];
    cout << c_array[0]->getEnter() << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas?

Here's the error:

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Comment: Who or what gave you the idea to use pointers? At all? Say `Customer customers[10];` and be done with it. Pointers should be banned from a first-year C++ course...

Comment: Must be a dynamic array. Sorry if I didn't make that clear.

Comment: Because the amount of customers will change dependent on a text file. It's for a simulation so the amount of customers will eventually change when I get that far.

Comment: Theoretically I guess I could make it super massive, but that defeats the purpose and limits my own abilities later on in the project.

Comment: @JamesRoseman: "Must be a dynamic array"; in that case, you want `std::vector<Customer> c_array(10);`. Unless your course is being taught backwards and you're not allowed to use containers, in which case `Customer * c_array = new Customer[10];` - and don't forget to `delete[]` is when you're done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Allocating an array of pointers does *not* allocate anything for what those pointers point to. So your statement:

```
c_array = new Customer*[10];
```

creates an array of pointers, but they point somewhere random (causing a segmentation fault when you try to dereference them). You will need to write a loop to initialise those pointers also.

Comment: Thanks! That was dumb of me, I just figured this out on my own to but you got to it faster than me!

Comment: @JamesRoseman Don't forget to select the answer that you found most helpful. [(Click)](http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png) It will also help others in the future if they stumble upon this SO question.

Answer (score 1):

By using `c_array = new Customer*[10]` you'll only create a bunch of pointers on the heap, you didn't allocate memory for your actual Customers. You have to allocate memory for every `Customer Object` after this. Use the following instead:

```
int main () {
    Customer* c_array[10];
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
         c_array[i] = new Customer;
    cout << c_array[0]->getEnter() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

or

```
int main () {
    Customer* c_array;
    c_array = new Customer[10];
    cout << c_array[0]->getEnter() << endl;
    delete[] c_array;
    return 0;
}
```

or

```
#include <vector>
int main () {
    std::vector<Customer> c_array(10);
    cout << c_array[0]->getEnter() << endl;     
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry Zeta, gave it to the guy who got there first, but thank you for the informative answer. I've never seen <vector> before.